# Как рассчитать скользящий максимум с начала календарной недели и месяца?

Tags: python, pandas

Скользящий максимум за 3 дня, все считает отлично:

```
df['Sales'].rolling('3D').max()
```

Скользящий максимум с начала календарной недели:

```
df['Sales'].rolling('W').max()
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ValueError: <Week: weekday=6> is a non-fixed frequency

С месяцем - аналогично.

[Датасет](https://dropmefiles.com/jhxha)

**Upd** `'7D'` и `'30D'` не подходят, т.к считают не с начала календарной недели и месяца.

**Вариант медленного решения:**

```
%timeit [df.loc[edt - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1):edt, 'Sales'].max() for edt in df.index]
```

> 397 ms ± 16.5 ms

Ищу решение, которое позволит делать эти операции быстро, датасеты тяжелые.

Comment: а если так `df['Sales'].rolling('7D').max()`?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru так будет цеплять предыдущую неделю. Нужно именно скользящий максимум в текущий момент с начала недели и начала месяца.

Comment: Может [это](https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/the-difference-between-the-expanding-and-rolling-window-in-pandas/) поможет.

Comment: https://discuss.dizzycoding.com/pandas-monthly-rolling-operation/

Comment: @TigerTV.ru предложил ссылку где описано правильное решение. 

Итог. Расширяющийся месячный максимум(недельный аналогично):

    sales['MM'] = [sales.loc[edt - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1):edt, 'Sales'].max() for edt in sales.index]  , для 1000 наблюдений эти рассчеты занимают 397ms, скорость несопоставима с .rolling. Для тяжелого датасета десятки секунд. Возможно есть более быстрые решения?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, вроде быстрее, предложенный не проверял, но этот отрабатывает примерно за 30-40 мс

```
df = pd.read_csv('/*/Sales.csv', sep=';').rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'Date'})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Сделайте столбцы с годом и неделей:

```
df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().year
df['WeekN'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
```

Дальше группируем, скидываем индекс и из листов с датами делаем столбец.
В конце можно скинуть индекс.

```
>>> df.groupby(['year', 'WeekN']).agg(Date=('Date', lambda x: x), max_of=('Sales', 'max')).reset_index(
    drop=True).explode('Date'))

        Date  max_of
0 2018-11-08  791958
0 2018-11-09  791958
1 2018-11-12  763447
1 2018-11-13  763447
1 2018-11-14  763447
1 2018-11-15  763447
1 2018-11-16  763447
2 2018-11-19  731052
2 2018-11-20  731052
2 2018-11-21  731052
2 2018-11-22  731052
2 2018-11-23  731052
3 2018-11-26  703182
3 2018-11-27  703182
```

Comment: предложенный вами вариант работает быстро. Но в максимумы записывает недельный максимум, вместо расширяющегося недельного максимума. Т.е. если пик продаж был в среду, то он известен уже в понедельник. Я пытаюсь найти решение для расширяющегося максимума внутри недели, без подглядывания в будущее. Пока не понимаю как доработать вариант, предложенный вами.